# Java Graph from file. Getting HashMap to remember object properties gathered in read from file

Tags: java, graph, hashmap

I am having problems with my buildMap function and creating the graph structure in my main method.  Any thoughts or help you have to offer are appreciated.  I am new to programming and working on creating my own classes in Java to create a graph data structure based on a file and then do some traveling sales person algorithms on it.

My graph structure creates looks like:

```
public class TSP_Graph {
// Hashmap where key is the geographic point and the pairs are of type   Office Node
// this connects each office node to a geographic point
private HashMap<GeographicPoint, OfficeNode> officeMap;
```

I read a file from my computer which has the geolocation of the office and some data on the office like advisors who are in it...

```
public static void buildMap(String filename, TSP_Graph map){
    // makes sure the reader is null
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    // neighbors is the hashset for keeping track of each officeNode created from the file.
    HashSet<OfficeNode> neighbors = new HashSet<OfficeNode>();
    Queue<OfficeNode> queue = new LinkedList<OfficeNode>();
    try{
        // nextline is a line to be parsed
        String nextLine;            

        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
        while ((nextLine = reader.readLine()) != null){
            // this is pulling in the Office Node from the the line.  It should have the advisors added to the node but they are not coming into the map
            OfficeNode office = splitInputString(nextLine);

            map.addOffice(office.getLocation());
            queue.add(office);
            neighbors.add(office);
        }
        reader.close();         

    } catch (IOException e){
        System.err.println("Problem loading file");
    }
    OfficeNode next = null;

    while(!queue.isEmpty()){
        next = queue.remove();
        for (OfficeNode neighbor : neighbors){
            if(next.getLocation() != neighbor.getLocation()){
                map.addOfficeEdge(next.getLocation(), neighbor.getLocation());
                next.addEdge(new OfficeEdge(next, neighbor));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm confused right now and can't seem to crack what's happening with my code.  When I call the loading function in my main method with:

```
System.out.println("Number of Offices: " + firstMap.getNumOffices());
    System.out.println("Number of Edges: " + firstMap.getNumEdges());

    for (OfficeNode node : firstMap.officeMap.values()){
        System.out.println("Data collected from main method");
        System.out.println("Number of Advisors " + node.getNumAdvisors());
        System.out.println("Number of Edges " + node.getNumEdges());
        System.out.println("Number of Advisor AUM total " + node.getOfficeAUM());
        System.out.println("Location:  " + node.getLocation());
    }
```

I am able to retrieve the geolocation for each object but get null for all the other data contained in the OfficeNode object using the getter methods.

In the file loading part of the code I've checked the data and it all pulls through ok.  Somewhere in my transmission from the buildMap function and the main method the data isn't making the journey.

Thanks for any help.

Here's my code for the splitInputString method:

```
private static OfficeNode splitInputString(String input){
    ArrayList<String> tokens = new ArrayList<String>();
    Pattern tokSplitter = Pattern.compile("[^\\s\"']+|\"([^\"]*)\"");
    Matcher m = tokSplitter.matcher(input);

    while (m.find()) {
        if (m.group(1) != null) {
            tokens.add(m.group(1)); 
        }
        else {
            tokens.add(m.group());
        }
    }

    double lat1 = Double.parseDouble(tokens.get(0));
    double lon1 = Double.parseDouble(tokens.get(1));
    // seems to be working correctly here
    OfficeNode node = new OfficeNode(new GeographicPoint(lat1, lon1));

    int count = 3;
    while(count < tokens.size()){

        node.addAdvisor(new FinancialAdvisor(tokens.get(count)));
        count++;
    }

    return node;
}
```

And for what it's worth here's the OfficeNode class:

```
public class OfficeNode {
// member variables
private GeographicPoint location;
private HashSet<OfficeEdge> officeEdges;
// set of advisors
private HashSet<FinancialAdvisor> advisors;
private long officeAUM;

OfficeNode(GeographicPoint loc){
    location = loc;
    officeEdges = new HashSet<OfficeEdge>();
    advisors = new HashSet<FinancialAdvisor>();
    officeAUM = 0;
}

// functions
// add a new edge to the node
void addEdge(OfficeEdge edge){
    officeEdges.add(edge);
}
// add a new advisor to the officeNode
void addAdvisor(FinancialAdvisor advisor){
    advisors.add(advisor);
}


// check for two nodes being equal or null being compared
public boolean equals(Object o){
    if(!(o instanceof OfficeNode) || (o == null)){
        return false;
    }
    OfficeNode node = (OfficeNode) o;
    return node.location.equals(this.location);
}

// getters
GeographicPoint getLocation(){
    return location;
}

HashSet<OfficeEdge> getEdges(){
    return this.officeEdges;
}

Set<FinancialAdvisor> getAdvisors(){
    return this.advisors;
}

int getNumAdvisors(){
    return this.advisors.size();
}

int getNumEdges(){
    return this.officeEdges.size();
}

long getOfficeAUM(){
    for (FinancialAdvisor advisor : advisors){
        officeAUM += advisor.getBookSize();
    }
    return this.officeAUM;
}
```

}

Comment: The problem lies not with your hashmap, but either with your construction of OfficeNode, or your implementation of its getter methods. You can check which by setting a breakpoint immediately after you create it, and examining the fields. Without seeing the code for `splitInputString()`, we can't tell you what went wrong.

Comment: Thank you for commenting, Andy.  I added breakpoints right after I create it in the splitInputString() and everything seemed to be correctly stored in the node being passed back at the object OfficeNode creation.  Still not sure what's going on and why it's not storing in the map.

Comment: I think this is the code that is throwing it off...    
public void addOffice(GeographicPoint location){
  // gets the location and creates the office node
  OfficeNode node = officeMap.get(location);
  // is this redundant?
  node = new OfficeNode(location);
  // puts the new office node and the location in the officeMap on key location
  officeMap.put(location, node);
  officeNodes.add(node);
 }

Comment: Got it working now.  Added a param of OfficeNode in addition to the GeographicPoint in the addOffice call.  The new OfficeNode was flushing out the data.